# Write Spark DF to csv file with array<string> data type

Tags: apache-spark, spark-csv

I am trying to write a spark DF with Array of string to a csv file, I followed the instructions provided in the  [site here](http://jimolonely.github.io/2018/01/03/spark/02-write-csv/)

But my column  also contains nulls, How can i handle the nulls and write the DF to file

Comment: a csv file can't have objects and arrays are objects. so you will have to convert array to string before you write to csv file

Comment: @user8371915 Thanks . The null case was recently added to the answer.